# Exit code 1 error when compiling the project

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I've been dealing with this issue for two days so far and the error came as soon as I moved my project over from my usb and onto my desktop:

[image]

I've tried:

1. Clearing the Derived Data folder
2. Clean build folder
3. Switching back to Legacy Build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem as you reference files from another directory that has no existence and that's because you didn't tick `copyToProject` when you dragged the files to the project , so you have to delete any red icon files that currently appear iin your project and find the source of these files and re-add them with copy